# Rmarkdown code chunks not interpreted

Tags: pdf, r, markdown

I'm using RStudio 0.98 on Kubuntu 15.04.  I am having difficulty creating Rmarkdown documents, specifically the ones that render a pdf output (and also Open Office).
The problem is that the *code chunks* that I'm embedding in the document aren't interpreted by the program.  For example, with the starting example
```` ```{r}
summary(cars)
``` ````
I only get the `summary(cars)` printed out, but not its code interpretation.

```
>  summary(cars)
     speed           dist       
 Min.   : 4.0   Min.   :  2.00  
 1st Qu.:12.0   1st Qu.: 26.00  
 Median :15.0   Median : 36.00  
 Mean   :15.4   Mean   : 42.98  
 3rd Qu.:19.0   3rd Qu.: 56.00  
 Max.   :25.0   Max.   :120.00
```

Would anyone know how to fix this?

By the way, I managed to include the code chunk above as code, with double ticks ``` `` ```, but not in the same chunk.  Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Do you have `eval=FALSE` set in the `setup-options` chunk?

Comment: No, I checked the `options("echo")` output to be TRUE.

Comment: `echo` is not the same as `eval`.

Comment: I actually did read them the same.  =p
It is -however- set to `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution for this problem.
It has nothing to do with the program configuration, but the way I was saving the markdown files.
Given that it is an Rmarkdown file, I need the `.Rmd` extension.
I was just using the `.md` extension which didn't allow me to *knit* the file before.